# How to link screen to list items in a Kivymd list

Tags: kivy, kivymd

I'm using ScreenManager. I would like to link the items in a OneLineListItem to new screen.

This is my KV file

```
screen_helper = """
    ScreenManager:

       GroupsScreen:
       MyGroupScreen:

<GroupsScreen>:
name: 'groups'
ScrollView:
    MDList:
        id: container_groups
        
<MyGroupScreen>:
name: 'my_group'
ScrollView:
    MDList:
        id: container_group

MDRectangleFlatButton:
    text: 'Back'
    pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.1}
    on_press: root.manager.current = 'groups'
```

and this is the python file

```
 class GroupsScreen(Screen):
     def on_enter(self, *args):
          for i in range(5):
              item = OneLineListItem(text='Gruppo ' + str(i))
              self.ids.container_groups.add_widget(item)





 class MyGroupScreen(Screen):
     pass

 sm = ScreenManager()
 sm.add_widget(GroupsScreen(name='groups'))
 sm.add_widget(MyGroupScreen(name='my_group'))

 class DemoApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Red"
        self.theme_cls.primary_hue = "500"
        screen = Builder.load_string(screen_helper)
        return screen
```

I would like to click on an item in the groups screen and go to MyGroupScreen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `OneLineListItem` class actually extends `ButtonBehavior`, so you can treat it like a `Button`. Just assign a `on_press` or `on_release` method to the `OneLineListItem`:

```
class GroupsScreen(Screen):
    def on_kv_post(self, *args):
        for i in range(5):
            item = OneLineListItem(text='Gruppo ' + str(i))
            item.on_release = self.switch_to_my_groups
            self.ids.container_groups.add_widget(item)

    def switch_to_my_groups(self, *args):
        self.manager.current = 'my_group'
```

I changed your `on_enter()` method to a `on_kv_post()` to be sure that the `kv` rules have been executed (so that the `ids` are available).

Another problem is the lines:

```
 sm = ScreenManager()
 sm.add_widget(GroupsScreen(name='groups'))
 sm.add_widget(MyGroupScreen(name='my_group'))
```

These lines should be removed. They attempt build the GUI, and then the result is not used. The line:

```
screen = Builder.load_string(screen_helper)
```

then rebuilds the GUI again, and this time it is actually used.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The on_release method works properly for the task, leaving on_enter() method. If I use on_kv_post(), an error occurs : ''' ValueError: KivyMD: App object must be initialized before loading root widget. '''.